# How to implement search input (autocomplete) of Google Maps with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google

I'm trying to implement the autocomplete input search Google Maps in my application, but I use the basemap the GeoServer and OpenLayers, I do not instantiate Google Maps, **and I can't**... I use this in OpenLayers:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map ({ div: "map" projection: new
OpenLayers.Projection ("EPSG: 900913") });
```

Remembering that, I instantiate the Maps API too:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=xxx&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

I saw this example above but I am not able to implement because use "*new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input)*" (see link above):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689705/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box (answer with more 33+)

Finally, I want to put the inputs (more then ONE, like 20 inputs) inside a FORM of one HTML page, **not on the map**